# Is there an anti-air radar in Bwala ya Masa?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Seems that I cannot get a chopper pick up here, but I cannot find a radar either

Comment: As an alternative, you can use the cardboard box to travel to the loading dock there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, there is not an anti-air radar in or near this village.**

The reasoning, so far as I can tell, is that with this village having some key involvement in

> the first mission to Africa, named "Pitch Dark"

precludes it from having a helicopter pick-up/drop-off location, since that would interfere with the narrative flow of said mission, seeing as

> it features the first appearance of child soldiers, which is a story thread that was obviously intended to be taken much further in the overall sequence of the story, but was cut short like so many other aspects of MGSV. :(